# Convert json to csv with js

Tags: javascript, json, csv, export-to-csv

I need to convert my JSON to a CSV file, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

I have this code already

```js
      let rows = typeof objArray !== "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
      let header = "";
      Object.keys(rows[0]).map(pr => (header += pr + ";"));

      let str = "";
      rows.forEach(row => {
        let line = "";
        let columns =
          typeof row !== "object" ? JSON.parse(row) : Object.values(row);

        columns.forEach(column => {
          if (line !== "") {
            line += ";";
          }
          if (typeof column === "object") {
            line += JSON.stringify(column);
          } else {
            line += column;
          }
        });
        str += line + "\r\n";
      });
      return header + "\r\n" + str;
```

But I expect a different result then what I have now

[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwaYe.png)

I need this [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7d2C.png)

```js
  function ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
      let rows = typeof objArray !== "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
      let header = "";
      Object.keys(rows[0]).map(pr => (header += pr + ";"));

      let str = "";
      rows.forEach(row => {
        let line = "";
        let columns =
          typeof row !== "object" ? JSON.parse(row) : Object.values(row);

        columns.forEach(column => {
          if (line !== "") {
            line += ";";
          }
          if (typeof column === "object") {
            line += JSON.stringify(column);
          } else {
            line += column;
          }
        });
        str += line + "\r\n";
      });
      return header + "\r\n" + str;
  }
  
  function downloadCSV () {
    let data = [{"am":{"a3":2,"a1":5,"a2":2},"zul":{"mer":1,"spi":1,"aut":1,"inf2":1,"int":1,"infl":1,"les":1},"kaab":      {"ka11":6,"ka12":6,"ka10":6},"kg3":"fdsf","ges":1,"alt":3,"kawe":{"ka9":4,"ka7":5,"ka8":5},"kaak":{"ka2":4,"ka3":5,"ka4":5,"ka1":4,"ka5":3,"ka6":5},"kg4":2,"kg1":5,"eink":"","kg2":4,"soz2":"","solz":"2","ae":{"a6":2,"a5":2,"a4":6}}]
    
    let result = ConvertToCSV(data);
    
    let fileToSave = new Blob([result], {
       type: "csv",
       name: 'data.csv
     });

     saveAs(fileToSave, 'data.csv);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.2/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="downloadCSV">download csv</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```js
function downloadCSV () {

    let arr = [{"am":{"a3":2,"a1":5,"a2":2},"zul":{"mer":1,"spi":1,"aut":1,"inf2":1,"int":1,"infl":1,"les":1},"kaab":      {"ka11":6,"ka12":6,"ka10":6},"kg3":"fdsf","ges":1,"alt":3,"kawe":{"ka9":4,"ka7":5,"ka8":5},"kaak":{"ka2":4,"ka3":5,"ka4":5,"ka1":4,"ka5":3,"ka6":5},"kg4":2,"kg1":5,"eink":"","kg2":4,"soz2":"","solz":"2","ae":{"a6":2,"a5":2,"a4":6}},
 {"am":{"a3":2,"a1":5,"a2":2},"zul":{"mer":1,"spi":1,"aut":1,"inf2":1,"int":1,"infl":1,"les":1},"kaab":      {"ka11":6,"ka12":6,"ka10":6},"kg3":"fdsf","ges":1,"alt":3,"kawe":{"ka9":4,"ka7":5,"ka8":5},"kaak":{"ka2":4,"ka3":5,"ka4":5,"ka1":4,"ka5":3,"ka6":5},"kg4":2,"kg1":5,"eink":"","kg2":4,"soz2":"","solz":"2","ae":{"a6":2,"a5":2,"a4":6}}   
    ];
  
    var keys = [];
    var values = [];
    function getKeys(data, k = '') {
      for (var i in data) {
        var rest = k.length ? '_' + i : i
        if (typeof data[i] == 'object') {
          if (!Array.isArray(data[i])) {
            getKeys(data[i], k + rest)
          }
        } else keys.push( k+ rest)
      }
    }   
    function getValues(data, k = '') {
      for (var i in data) {
        var rest = k.length ? '' + i : i
        if (typeof data[i] == 'object') {
          if (!Array.isArray(data[i])) {
            getValues(data[i], k + rest)
          }
        }
        else values.push(data[rest])
      }
    }

    getKeys(arr[0])
    var value="";
    arr.forEach(x=>{
       values=[];
       getValues(x);
       value+=values.join(";")+"\r\n";
    })
    
    let result = keys.join(";")+"\r\n"+value;
    let fileToSave = new Blob([result], {
       type: "csv",
       name: 'data.csv'
     });
        
    saveAs(fileToSave, 'data.csv');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.2/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="downloadCSV()">download csv</button>
```

Comment: this looks much better. Thank you

Comment: But all the data is in one row, thats a problem

Comment: I need to have for each main object one row in excel file

Comment: I need to have one row for each object
So if inside the let arr= [{}, {}, {}] more objects

Comment: Yeah that better.
But one last thing:

Comment: How can I also add the object keys like `kawe`, 'kaak' and so on?

Comment: something like kaak_ka2 kaak_ka3 and so on

Comment: I already did in answer I think you took before last edit can u check answer again ?

Comment: How can I short the array with the objects so that always 'am' is at the beginning?